# ext4 signature detected on /dev/sdb1 at offset 1080 while creating Gluster cluster

Tags: glusterfs

[image]

I am getting attached error while creating Gluster cluster on Kubernetes. Can someone please advice why this error is coming and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solved by by using the command wipefs -a /dev/sdb1. It wipes the signature present on newly created partition.